mysql Duplicate row 50 times but change the date recurring interval
Hi I have a table called work_events ( id, date_time, title).
It has 1 row: (1,2024-09-07 11:00, GroupMeeting)
No, i want to copy that row like 51 times. the only thing is that the date on each row moves on 7 days....so basiclly I want the same row recurring every week...as this is actually shown in a calendar.
However, it has to be a copy of rows...so each event has its own row...the id needs to increase
IS there an a way to do this using sql?

Hint: recursive cte. (Or emacs script.)

Do you want to increase id for each row too?

yes increase the id for each row...

You can use a recursive CTE where you select the next 51 id's, meaning id's 2-52.
INSERT INTO work_events(id, date_time, title)
  WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   SELECT 2 AS i
   UNION ALL
   SELECT i + 1
   FROM cte
   WHERE i < 52
  )
  SELECT i, DATE_ADD('2024-09-07 11:00:00', INTERVAL i-1 WEEK), 'Group Meeting'
  FROM cte;

Then you insert based on the result of that CTE. The id to insert is the increasing number from the CTE. The date to insert will be calculated by the date you already have plus the number of weeks based on the running number.
Take care to substract one from the running number as you already have id 1, so you will start by 2.
After running above insert commands, your table will contain 52 rows as you requested.
Note: I read the question as if you really want to insert rows. If you only want to select them, just remove the INSERT in the beginning and rather add the original column alias:
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   SELECT 2 AS i
   UNION ALL
   SELECT i + 1
   FROM cte
   WHERE i < 52
  )
  SELECT 
    i AS id, 
    DATE_ADD('2024-09-07 11:00:00', INTERVAL i-1 WEEK) AS date_time, 
    'Group Meeting' AS title
  FROM cte;

See this sample fiddle
